# TypeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object does not support indexing

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer, typeerror

How to find the distance between two points in same layer?

I tried the following with no success:

```py
from qgis.core import QGis

lyr = QgsVectorLayer("D:/QGIS/qgis_data/nyc/NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO.shp","Museums", "ogr")
#fts = lyr.getFeatures()
l = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(lyr)
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    last = f
    d = QgsDistanceArea()
    m = d.measureLine(first.geometry().asPoint(), last.geometry().asPoint())
    deg = QGis.DecimalDegrees
    met = QGis.Meters
    d.convertMeasurement(m, deg, met, False)
```

and go the following error:

> TypeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object does not support indexing

Comment: I need to measure the distance btwn two points. I tried manually giving the point 1 and point2 value point1 = QgsPoint(80.69,12.56)
point2 = QgsPoint(80.02,14.20)
#Create a measure object
distance = QgsDistanceArea()
distance.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
distance = point1.distance(point2)
print(distance)          This code is working fine.. but i need to measure the distance by the name of the region through pycode  . so tried above code which mentioned not success.. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try storing your data in a dictionary:

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ne_10m_populated_places_simple')[0]

#Create a dictionary of placename and point geometry. Change 'name' to your columnname. (This wont work with duplicates on name though!)
namegeom = {f['name']:f.geometry().asPoint() for f in lyr.getFeatures()}

distance = QgsDistanceArea()
distance.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

def distanceInMeters(city1, city2):
 """return the distance between two cities"""
    return distance.measureLine(namegeom[city1], namegeom[city2])

print(distanceInMeters('Las Vegas', 'Flagstaff'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks BERA.. It is working fine

Comment: Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox if it solved your question